# python decorators in interpreter

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

how to use this code in python interactive shell (interpreter):

```
@makebold
@makeitalic
def hello():
    print ("Hello, world!")
```

in shell I get this error:

```
>>> @makebold
...     hello()
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    hello()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> @makebold
... hello()
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    hello()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: It's not clear what OP wanted to accomplish with the attempts at the REPL; the accepted answer offers multiple possible interpretations. I closed as a duplicate for one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to decorate an *expression*; you forgot to use `def` and in one case you even *indented* the `hello()` line. The same code in a Python file will fail with the same errors, there is no difference between the interactive interpreter and a Python source file here.

Decorators only work on classes and functions; if you actually tried to use this with a function definition statement it'd work just fine:

```
>>> def foo(f):
...     return f
... 
>>> @foo
... def bar():
...     pass
...
```

If you wanted to apply it to an existing function, you'd need to use:

```
>>> hello = makebold(hello)
```

because that is exactly what the `@expression` syntax ends up doing.